# .remove() or selector behavior in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

```
function updateSelector()
{
    //select all drop down list of field selector
    var fieldSelector = $("select:not(#project):not(#allNo):not(#availableNo)");
    var selected;
    //copy full option list from static drop down list to temp drop down list
    $("#availableNo").empty().append($("#allNo").clone());
    //remove any selected option from temp option
    fieldSelector.each(function() {
        $("#availableNo"+" option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").remove();
    });
    //copy temp option to all field selector
    fieldSelector.each(function() {
        //store selected option for current dropdown
        selected = $("option:selected", this);
        //clear list then append stored selected option
        $(this).empty().append(selected);
        //append temp option to current dropdown
        $(this).append($("#availableNo option").clone());
        //add blank option
        if($("option",this).length ==1)
            $(this).append("<option></option>");
    });
    //alert("..");
}
```

The code above is working fine but in IE it seems like it will behave strangely if there is a  statement after it (no problem if there is no statdment after it, and it is only IE that has a problem with it).

If I alert (in last line) the selected option will move by 1 index.

For example, if there is 1-4 select 1 will result in select 2; if select 2 it will be 3.

Does anyone know why or what causes this?

I'm really frustrated with this..

Comment: try after changing `"` to `'` and write like this  `$("#availableNo > option[value='+$(this).val()']").remove();`

Comment: this didn't work ,it wasn't remove option.
I'm still confusing what's going on.It look fine for me :(

Comment: If I add alert($(this).val()); before or after removing they will work correctly,what the hell is this LOL....

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the conditional at the bottom in curly brackets — `if() {…}`?

Comment: will u create a fiddle for this?? go to http://www.jsfiddle.net and paste your current code with HTML & JS, and refer the link here :)